# how to read .shp & .dbf file in jupyter when using geopandas

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geopandas, shapefile, dbf

we are using .shp & .dbf files
these files are read as str (string) files
we want these files to be read as
geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from geopandas import geoseries,geodataframe
    
import os
os.getcwd()
shape_file = ('/drive/notebooks/cb_2018_us_state_500k.dbf')
type(shape_file)
```

Comment: did you look at the "introduction to geopandas" tutorial on the website? the first section after "installation" is titled "reading and writing files"

Comment: you @PaulH mean https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/introduction.html

Comment: Yup. That's the one